# Firebase C# Update&Delete Operations

Tags: c#, firebase

I am developing a desktop application which communicates with our mobile application. They use Firebase as database but since Firebase doesn't support C# I am having really hard times. I could find a solution for Select&Insert operations but I am really stacked at Update&Delete operations.

```
   public void recordEntry(Record rec) {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rec);
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("firebaseLink");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        json = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
    }
```

And a part of select function is like:

```
 public List<RecordUI> FillDataGridView()
    {
        string result = null;
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("firebaseLink");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        try
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Encoding responseEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), responseEncoding))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            JObject json = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
```

I've tried "request.Method = "DELETE" but it deletes all the database. I think I need a kind of SQL command to delete and update but no idea how to insert it into a Http Request. Any ideas?